# How to give this simple c++ program a proper loop

Tags: c++

I am a programming beginner and I am doing one exercise that I found on the internet:

Make a calculator that takes 3 inputs and adds, subtracts, multiplies or divides two numbers.
The first and third input being ints. The second being a char.

1. Use a switch statement to figure out what operation to do depending on the user input.
2. Use at least one function.
3. Have the program ask again if the input is invalid.
4. Make the program loop after completion, allowing multiple uses before it exits completely.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int number1 , number2;
char operator_;
cout << "enter first number:" << endl;
cin >> number1;

cout << "enter operator:";
cin >> operator_;

cout << "enter second number:" << endl;
cin >> number2;

switch (operator_)
{
case '+':
    cout << " the sum is " << number1 + number2;
    break;

case '-':
    cout << "the difference is " <<number1 - number2;
    break;

case '*':
    cout <<  "the product is " << number1 * number2;
    break;

case '/':
    cout << "the quotient is " << number1 / number2;
    break;

default:
    cout << "Invalid Operation";
}

return 0;
}
```

How can I accomplish task 3 and 4? I studied while loops but I don't know how that is gonna help with my program.thanks

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a site to post homework. Thats why you are receiving downvotes

Comment: "I studied while loops but I don't know how that is gonna help with my program", how would you solve it without?

Comment: This is not a homework, I promise. I got it from the new boston forum c++ section because I was watching tutorials from that site, but the guy who asked it isn't responding right now.

Answer (score 2):

Just add an infinite loop outside all your code in the `main` function, and at the end ask the user if he/she wants to continue. If not then `break` out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could do both in one go if you like.

First rename your main function, call it something like do_calculation.

Now write a new main function. This one will contain a loop to ask if the users wants to try again, and it will call the do_calculation function you've just created. Something like this

```
int main()
{
    char try_again;
    do
    {
        do_calculation();
        cout << "Do you want to try again (answer Y or N) ";
        cin >> try_again;
    }
    while (try_again == 'y' || try_again == 'Y');
}
```

Comment: While it is usually good, to include code snippets, I think that, in this lazy questions, (especially if they are homework) you should just give a general hint on how to solve their problems without using explicit code, as it encourage copy-pasta rather than actual understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: This could be improved by using `while (toupper(try_again) == 'Y');` which reduces the need for two compares.